# Hide elements in jQuery based on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a filtering tool using a select element. When you choose something from the drop down, it should filter the divs below to show only the div for that item.

I am targeting the divs using the select value which is also the class of the div the item is in. So for example, if you choose shirts in the drop down the value would be item-shirts and a div below would have a class of item-shirts.

I have figured out how to hide everything that doesn't have the class of the selected item when something is selected. But I can't figure out how to unhide everything when something else is selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my HTML

```
<select>
   <option value="item-shirts">Shirts</option>
   <option value="item-shoes">Shoes</option>
   <option value="item-shoes">Pants</option>
</select>

<div class="item-section item-shirt></div>
<div class="item-section item-shoes></div>
<div class="item-section item-pants></div>
```

Here is my jQuery

```
$('select').on("change", function() {
    var value = $('select').val();
   if($('.item-section').hasClass(value)) {
      $('.item-section.'+value).siblings().hide();
   } else {
      $('.item-section.'+value).siblings().show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to adding an active class to a list/group of elements. Typically what you do is loop through all the elements removing the active class (even though it's only applied to one element), then add the active class to the specific element. In your case you might want to hide all DIVs, then show the specific DIV.

```js
var $sections = $( '.item-section' );

$('select').on( 'change', function ( e ) {

  $sections.hide();
  $( '.' + this.value ).show();
  
} );
```

```css
.item-section {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
   <option value="item-shirts">Shirts</option>
   <option value="item-shoes">Shoes</option>
   <option value="item-pants">Pants</option>
</select>

<div class="item-section item-shirts">Shirt</div>
<div class="item-section item-shoes">Shoes</div>
<div class="item-section item-pants">Pants</div>
```

**Note:** You had a few errors in your markup that I changed to make everything work. i.e. Duplicate values for your `<option>` tags and some missing quotes.

I've done a couple performance improvements too.

- You also don't need `$( 'select' ).val()` inside of your event handler. The context of the handler is the `<select>` element so you can use the `this.value` instead and skip jQuery querying the DOM to do the same.
- I've also cached the `.item-section` elements so you're not querying the DOM over and over again on each change of the select.

Answer (score 0):

There was no need to test for `hasClass()`.  All you need to do is get the value from the selected option and show the `<div>` having that class.  I added an extra empty option so that when you select it, it will show all `<div>`s.

```js
$('select').on("change", function() {
  var value = $('select').val();

  if (value) {
    $(".item-section").hide();
    $("." + value).show();
  } else {
    $(".item-section").show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="item-shirt">Shirts</option>
   <option value="item-shoes">Shoes</option>
   <option value="item-shoes">Pants</option>
</select>

<div class="item-section item-shirt">Shirts</div>
<div class="item-section item-shoes">Shoes</div>
<div class="item-section item-pants">Pants</div>
```